# Javascript JQuery Recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, siblings

I am writing a javascript recursion function but in always gave me 0 value. Below is my code snippet and a screenshot showing the markup:

```
    getOdometerEnd: function(object){
    var previous = jQuery(object).closest('tr').prevAll();
    var odometerEnd = parseInt(previous.find('input[name=odometer_end\\[\\]]').val());
    console.log(previous.find('input[name=destination\\[\\]]').val());
    if(odometerEnd == 0){
        this.getOdometerEnd(previous);
    }
    return odometerEnd;
},
updateOdometer: function(){
    var self = this;
    var distance = 0;
    var odometerStart = 0;
    var odometerEnd = 0;
    jQuery('.app-table tr').each(function(index, object){
        distance = jQuery(object).find('input[name=distance\\[\\]]').val();
        if(typeof distance != 'undefined' && distance > 0){
            if(index == 1){
                odometerStart = jQuery(object).find('input[name=vehicle_odometer\\[\\]]').val();
            }else {
                odometerStart = self.getOdometerEnd(object);
            }
            odometerEnd = parseInt(odometerStart)+parseInt(self.userDistance(distance));
            jQuery(object).find('input[name=odometer_start\\[\\]]').val(odometerStart);
            jQuery(object).find('input[name=odometer_end\\[\\]]').val(odometerEnd);
        }

    });
},
```

I don't know where I have mistaken, but it gives me the correct value at second last recursion but at last it again returns 0.
Can you help me please.
I've attached an image showing my markup here.

P.S. Stack overflow didn't allowed me to post image. Alternatively you can view image here: http://www.yourcarlog.com/odometer-problem.jpg

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Try `return this.getOdometerEnd(previous);`

Comment: No it didn't helped me, firebug error console says:
Timestamp: 11/18/2012 6:49:07 PM
Error: too much recursion

Comment: Binod, in words, what are your rules for fetching odometer start/end data from previous rows?

Comment: Hi Beetroot,
What I want to do is, for the first row fetch the predefined value for odometer start and then add the distance calculated from google map api to make odometer end for that row. Then for the next row, odometer start will be odometer end from previous row. Everything is well until there is a row where no distance is calculated. At that row there won't be any odometer start and end. Now on next row again the distance calculated. Then I want odometer end from the row where there is odometer data. Then want to fetch odometer from that row to current row
Guess I was able to explain. :)

Comment: Aha, in that case I think what can do is to change the rule for handling the case where no distance is calculated. If you allow such rows to follow exactly **the same rules** as all other rows, then their odo_start will be the same as odo_end and the latter value will simply propagate through to the following row as its odo_start. Thus, the need to handle zero distance as a special case disappears.

Comment: No Beetroot, I cannot propagate the same value for odometer start and end to the row where there is no distance calculated, I need this data blank for other calculations. Anyway, thank you for the time to look on the issue, I really appreciate. If you have other suggestions you can share.

Comment: Binod, it really makes better sense for odo_end to propagate through null rows. `Start: 0` `End: 0` makes no sense in the user interface. In your example the last but one row **should** read `Start: 15617` `End: 15617`, which will be 100% logical to the user. Zeros are not logical. Elsewhere, you can handle the case where `distance == 0` without testing the Start/End values themselves. I've done this sort of stuff before and, honestly, make the conceptual leap and you won't regret it.

Comment: He he, I managed to solve it my self, just change the above function to this:

 getOdometerEnd: function(object){
  var previous = jQuery(object).closest('tr').prevAll();
  var odometerEnd = parseInt(previous.find('input[name=odometer_end\\[\\]]').val());
  if(odometerEnd == 0){
   odometerEnd = this.getOdometerEnd(previous);
  }
  return odometerEnd;
 },


i.e. instead of this.getOdometerEnd(previous);

use

odometerEnd = this.getOdometerEnd(previous);

Comment: Binod, if that works then fine - recursive solutions alway give one a nice intellectual warm feeling. However, recursion isn't necessary here. I'm about to post a solution based on a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, give the elements classes to make selection easier and quicker. Selection by name is cumbersome.

Second, you will find it much simpler and probably no less efficient to :

- maintain a running `odo_cumulative` variable, thus avoiding the need to sniff up the table for a valid earlier value of `odo_end`.
- set the `odo_start` and `odo_end` values unconditionally, thus allowing `odo_cumulative` to propagate through null rows.
- (if you must) perform a second row-scan to zero out `odo_start` and `odo_end` in null rows.

Replace `updateOdometer` with the following version:

```
updateOdometer: function(){
    var self = this;
    var odo_cumulative;
    var $rows = jQuery('.app-table tr').each(function(index, tr){
        var $tr = jQuery(tr);
        if(!odo_cumulative) {
            odo_cumulative = parseInt($tr.find('input.vehicle_odometer').val());
        }
        var odo_start = odo_cumulative;
        var odo_cumulative = odo_end = parseInt(odo_start) + parseInt(self.userDistance($tr.find('input.distance').val()));
        $tr.find('input.odometer_start').val(odo_start);
        $tr.find('input.odometer_end').val(odo_end);
    });
    //Now, if you absolutely must, :) DESPITE BEING TOTALLY ILLOGICAL AND AGAINST ALL MY ADVICE :), scan the table rows again to zero out the start/end values where distance ==0;
    $rows.each(function(index, tr){
        var $tr = jQuery(tr);
        if(parseInt($tr.find('input.distance').val()) == 0){
            $tr.find('input.odometer_start, input.odometer_end').val(0);
        }
    });
},
```

*untested*

Third, the `getOdometerEnd` method is no longer called so can be deleted unless needed elsewhere.

### EDIT:

And if that works, then so should this, which is even simpler, avoiding the need to double scan:

```
updateOdometer: function(){
    var self = this,
        odo_cumulative;
    var $rows = jQuery('.app-table tr').each(function(index, tr){
        var $tr = jQuery(tr),
            $inputs = $tr.find('input'),
            distance = parseInt(self.userDistance($inputs.filter('.distance').val()));
        if(!odo_cumulative) {
            odo_cumulative = parseInt($inputs.filter('.vehicle_odometer').val());
        }
        $inputs.filter('.odometer_start').val((distance == 0) ? 0 : odo_cumulative);
        odo_cumulative += distance;
        $inputs.filter('.odometer_end').val((distance == 0) ? 0 : odo_cumulative);
    });
},
```

*untested*

Comment: Thanx Beetroot,
I really appreciate your help. It helped me. :)